# Is there a way to filter a log file based on the date read as argument?

Tags: shell, date, awk, filter

I'm processing this log file:

```
2021-03-21 20:06:45; ABC; 531.54
2021-03-21 20:06:47; DEF; 136. 81
2021-03-21 20:06:51; GHI; 222.34
```

I was wondering whether it's possible to use awk to create a filter for the file so that the only lines printed out after applying it are the ones which dates are later than the date given to the script as an argument.
I run the script as:

```
./script -a 2021-03-21 20:06:46
```

And expect the output to be:

```
2021-03-21 20:06:47; DEF; 136. 81
2021-03-21 20:06:51; GHI; 222.34
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `awk` isn't going to be a great tool for this task, since it doesn't know anything about filtering dates. Just about any higher level language (python/ruby/php/perl/etc) has built-in features for parsing dates that will make this task much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GNU Awk` which supports the `mktime()` function is available, would please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

dy=$1   # e.g. "2021-03-21"
tm=$2   # e.g. "20:06:46"

awk -F ";" -v dy="$dy" -v tm="$tm" '            # pass bash arguments to awk
    BEGIN { gsub("-", " ", dy); gsub(":", " ", tm); given = mktime(dy " " tm) }
                                                # convert the passed day&time to the seconds since the epoch
    {
        str = $1; gsub("[-:]", " ", str)        # extract the timestamp out of the log line
        sec = mktime(str)                       # convert it to the seconds since the epoch
        if (sec > given) print                  # compare with the given day&time
    }
' file.log
```

Save the script above as a file, say `script`, add the executable permission with `chmod a+x script`, then invoke with something like `./script 2021-03-21 20:06:46`.
The output will be:

```
2021-03-21 20:06:47; DEF; 136. 81
2021-03-21 20:06:51; GHI; 222.34
```

**[Alteranative]**
Even without the `mktime()` function, you can just say:

```
awk -F ";" -v dy="$1" -v tm="$2" '
    $1 > dy " " tm
' file.log
```

which will output the same result. This works because the given date and time string can be compared in a dictionary order.